# Azure Powershell - Problem with assigning private IP address to an NIC

Tags: networking, azure-powershell

Here is my script

```
$my_vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name <vnet_name>
$my_subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name <subnet_name> -VirtualNetwork $my_vnet
Add-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name ext-ipconfig6 -NetworkInterface $my_nic - 
Subnet $my_subnet -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.0.6
```

There is no error when running the script. If I use the following command to check, I do see the  IP object created.

```
Get-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name ext-ipconfig6 -NetworkInterface $my_nic
...
{
  "Name": "ext-ipconfig6",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.6",
  "PrivateIpAllocationMethod": "Static",
  "Subnet": {
    "Id": "blabla"
  },
  "Primary": false
}
```

However, I don't see it created on the portal.

Comparing with others created in the portal, I see other properties like `Etag`, `Id`, `ProvisioningState`, ...etc. Where did I do wrong...?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You are just creating the Network Interface IP configuration and not setting it to the existing Network interface itself.***

**I tested the same script which resulted as below :**

[image]
[image]

***To fix the above you will have to add `| Set-AzNetworkInterface` after the `Add-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig` command like below :***

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "ansuman-vnet" -ResourceGroupName "ansumantest" 
$nic= Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name "ansumannic01" -ResourceGroupName "ansumantest"
Add-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "IPConfig2" -NetworkInterface $nic -Subnet $vnet.Subnets[0]  -PrivateIpAddress "10.0.0.7" | Set-AzNetworkInterface
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: You fixed it! thank you very much